# How to Send across variables when using mouse listener in java

Tags: java, mouseevent, jtextfield

This is my code:

```
JTextField[] _CreatePlayers = new JTextField[3];
    for (int i = 1; i < _CreatePlayers.length; i++) {
        _CreatePlayers[i] = new JTextField("Player " + i+" input name here");
        _CreatePlayers[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            _CreatePlayers[i].setText("");  <- error is here as i is not inside the class made by mouse click
        }
    });
        _2Player.add(_CreatePlayers[i]);
    }
```

i am unsure how to fix this issue as i am not very experienced with event driven programming

Comment: Did you try making `_CreatePlayers` final ?

Comment: yeah the issue is with the `i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple workaround:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < _CreatePlayers.length; i++) {
        final int finalI = i;
        _CreatePlayers[i] = new JTextField("Player " + i+" input name here");
        _CreatePlayers[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                _CreatePlayers[finalI].setText("");
            }
        });
    }
```